# Issue linking to libpng when trying to make pngnq on Linux

Tags: linker, undefined-reference, libpng

I am trying to install [pngnq](http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/), which relies on [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) >= 1.2.8.  I have installed `libpng` 1.5.7 via `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` (without problems), because the `libpng` version in the Software Center was too old.  I am now trying to install `pngnq` via `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` (again, because Software Center version is too old), but am getting stuck at the `make` step on error messages which I believe pertain to `libpng` linking.  A small sample of the error messages:

```
undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
undefined reference to `png_convert_from_time_t'
undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE'
```

I have limited experience with installing software manually on Linux, and so am not really sure what the next step is in diagnosing the problem.  I've done substantial searching, but haven't really found anything targeted at the issue I'm having.  Based on a forum post on a similar-ish issue I've done an `ls` on `/usr/local/lib` directory and found:

```
libpng15.a   libpng15.so.15   libpng.la   libpng15.la  
libpng15.so.15.7.0   libpng.so   libpng15.so   libpng.a
```

though I don't know if that's actually any use in diagnosing/ruling out certain problems.  Can anyone advise what might be wrong, keeping in my my minimal experience with compiling code on Linux?

Edit:

As requested, here is a sample of the trace beginning at the `make` call:

```
bryce@whatever:~/Downloads/pngnq-1.1$ make
Making all in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/bryce/Downloads/pngnq-1.1/src'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/bryce/Downloads/pngnq-1.1/src'
gcc `libpng-config --I_opts` -Wall --pedantic -std=gnu99 -g -O2 `libpng-config 
--ldflags` -lz  -o pngnq pngnq.o neuquant32.o rwpng.o  -lm -lz 
pngnq.o: In function `pngnq':
/home/bryce/Downloads/pngnq-1.1/src/pngnq.c:518: undefined reference to `png_get_gAMA'
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm encountering the same issue compiling pngnq.

Comment: @ColinO'Dell been ages since I've looked at this, but I'm pretty sure I gave up and used a version on a Mac machine instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like includes don't match the library. Double check to see if you've got png.h in /usr/include or libpng* in /usr/lib/.

Also show the gcc line that shows up before you see the error. That might point to the issue.

Comment: I have `png.h` in `/usr/include`, but do not have `libpng*` in `/usr/lib`

Comment: Try this - if you're a bash user, export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH, then remake.. If you're a csh user.. I forget, but basically /usr/local/bin needs to be _first_ in your $PATH. That should get libpng-config picked up from /usr/local/bin, which will in turn emit the correct configuration information for your app.

Comment: Tried `export PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH` as suggested, but alas the same error prevails.